# Kubuntu 18.04 - desktop breaks changing xrandr/monitors

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, xrandr

I run two xrandr commands when unplugging/plugging in monitors.

Plugging in:

`xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 2880x1800 --pos 1456x1620 --output HDMI2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 2880x0 --scale 1.5x1.5 --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --scale 1.5x1.5`

Unplugging:

`xrandr --output HDMI1 --off --output HDMI2 --off`

I have to use xrandr because of the complicated scaling.

But, about 25% of the time when running these commands I end up with a broken desktop, in a way that is hard to describe.

- the task bar will end up going across the middle of the screen as opposed to the bottom where it is supposed to be
- you can move the cursor around
- you can't click on anything
- you can't type anything

It would be best if this doesn't happen at all, but even having a way to recover from this would be nice. I've tried restarting plasma and resetting xrandr from virtual terminals, but have not had any luck.

Comment: From left to right you should have HDMI2, eDP1, HDM1. Why eDP1 position is 1456x1620 ? Its x coordinate should be at least 1920 otherwise it will overlap to HDM1.

Comment: For more context the there are two monitors side by side, and then one below the two.

Comment: Of course I forgot about y translation. Your configuration should be ok. I've just tried some settings on my three setup monitor (side by side) and I found some problems too. The only way that I found to simply recover the screen resolution is to log out and log back in. This may be differ from you since I am on stock ubuntu (using gdm3 and xorg).
You should try seeing the output of `xrandr` when the issue appears to see what's wrong with the configuration.

Comment: Good call, I have the commands in a shell script that I can launch via alt-f2 when I come and go from my desk (it's a work computer), but I'm not logging anywhere. I'll add in the logging tomorrow!